# Why is the scrollTop of two div not equal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the left div's scrollTop by the scrollTop of the right div.  As you can see, when I scroll on the right div, the left div is lagging.  how to scrollTop both equally so that there is no delay?
This is my code:

```js
(function() {
  const scrollLeft = document.querySelector("#scroll-left");
  const scrollRight = document.querySelector("#scroll-right");
  const num1 = document.querySelector("#num-1");
  const num2 = document.querySelector("#num-2");

  let lastScroll = 0;

  scrollRight.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let currentScroll = this.scrollTop;

    num1.innerHTML = 'scrollLeft: ' + scrollLeft.scrollTop
    num2.innerHTML = 'scrollRight: ' + scrollRight.scrollTop

    scrollLeft.scrollTop = currentScroll

  });

})();
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

.scroll-y {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scroll-right {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h6 id="num-1">00</h6>
        <h6 id="num-2">00</h6>
        <div id="scroll-left" class="scroll-y">
          <div style="height: 1000px">
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
            The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now
            use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and
            the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
            it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
            Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
            looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and
            web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
            (injected humour and the like).
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 -->

      <div class="col-6">
        <h6>Scroll below</h6>
        <div id="scroll-right" class="scroll-y">
          <div style="height: 1000px">
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
            The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now
            use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and
            the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
            it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
            Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
            looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and
            web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
            (injected humour and the like).
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- container -->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsnm8c4a/

Comment: This is entirely a guess, but: I would imagine there is some debouncing in the function that keeps the two scroll sections in sync, which could mean you are printing out the position before it's finished changing.

Comment: I am not sure you can get no lag because the scroll event doesn’t fire in every pixel scrolled and scrolling has already happened on the right by the time you are alerted to it. Maybe turning scrolling off and implementing your own is the only way to get such fine control?

Comment: if I create another div above it and scroll through it, it will have no more lag.  but will no longer be able to select the content below it
https://jsfiddle.net/cn327pLa/

Answer (score 0):

You see a lag in the numbers showing the scrollTops of the two divs because you update that display before you have updated the left div's scrollTop to match the right one - you do it immediately afterwards.

The actual lag is barely perceptable if it's there at all (sometimes I think maybe I'm seeing it, sometimes not) and would not matter to a user in practice as it's a tiny fraction of a second.

To get the two displays correct you need to alter the sequence in the event handling function to:

```
  scrollRight.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let currentScroll = this.scrollTop;    
    scrollLeft.scrollTop = currentScroll;

    num1.innerHTML = 'scrollLeft: ' + scrollLeft.scrollTop
    num2.innerHTML = 'scrollRight: ' + scrollRight.scrollTop

  });
```

Otherwise  you are showing the old scrollTop for the left div even though it will be the same as the right one on the next frame.

```js
(function() {
  const scrollLeft = document.querySelector("#scroll-left");
  const scrollRight = document.querySelector("#scroll-right");
  const num1 = document.querySelector("#num-1");
  const num2 = document.querySelector("#num-2");

  let lastScroll = 0;

  scrollRight.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let currentScroll = this.scrollTop;    

    scrollLeft.scrollTop = currentScroll
    num1.innerHTML = 'scrollLeft: ' + scrollLeft.scrollTop
    num2.innerHTML = 'scrollRight: ' + scrollRight.scrollTop

  });

})();
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

.scroll-y {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scroll-right {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h6 id="num-1">00</h6>
        <h6 id="num-2">00</h6>
        <div id="scroll-left" class="scroll-y">
          <div style="height: 1000px">
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
            The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now
            use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and
            the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
            it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
            Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
            looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and
            web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
            (injected humour and the like).
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 -->

      <div class="col-6">
        <h6>Scroll below</h6>
        <div id="scroll-right" class="scroll-y">
          <div style="height: 1000px">
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
            The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now
            use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and
            the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
            it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
            Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
            looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and
            web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
            (injected humour and the like).
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- container -->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

I wondered about looking into passive as an option on scrolling (to get the scrolling fully done before you have a look through the eventlistener) but I doubt if it's worth it in practice.